# PR2 arm planning is not shown in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, rviz, moveit, pr2, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi my friends,

I have a problem following the tutorial on Moveit! [here](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/PR2/Gazebo/Quick_Start)

I follow exactly what the tutorial says, the pr2 can plan an arm trajectory and show the animation in Rviz, however when i click the Execute button on the Motion Planning panel, the pr2 in gazebo does nothing. The error message i received from rviz is as follows:

```
 [ERROR] [1378352167.379469133, 105.504000000]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ l_elbow_flex_joint l_forearm_roll_joint l_shoulder_lift_joint l_shoulder_pan_joint l_upper_arm_roll_joint l_wrist_flex_joint l_wrist_roll_joint ]
```

But i am sure i also follow the tutorial [here](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/PR2/Setup_Assistant/Quick_Start#Pre-requisites) to setup the configurations.

Can someone help to solve the problem.
I am running on groovy Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

Thanks a lot in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76489/pr2-arm-planning-is-not-shown-in-gazebo/) by [ljk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5470/ljk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2013-09-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-11-14**:
@ljk please don't use # symbol in tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

problem solved by install moveit plugins

sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-pr2-moveit-plugins

---

Originally posted by [ljk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5470/ljk/) with karma: 155 on 2013-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1